# On using Multipartparser or formparser classes Swagger documentation won't load, the error - "cannot instantiate nested serializer as Parameter"

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I am using a nested serializer as shown below, doc_file is a filefield -

```
class Documents_ManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Documents_Manager
        fields = ['id', 'doc_type', 'doc_file']


class IndexDetailsCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    methodology_file = Documents_ManagerSerializer()
    Factsheet_file = Documents_ManagerSerializer()
    Indexvalues_file = Documents_ManagerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = IndexDetails
        fields = ['id', 'Tab_id', 'Name' ,'methodology_file','Factsheet_file','Indexvalues_file']
```

I am using parser classes = Multipartparser and formparser to upload files in swagger documentation, following is my views code -

```
@method_decorator(name='create', decorator=IndexDetailsSwagger.create())
@method_decorator(name='partial_update', decorator=IndexDetailsSwagger.update())

class IndexDetailsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset = IndexDetails.objects.filter(Valid=True).all()
    serializer_class = IndexDetailsSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch']


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ["create"]:
            return IndexDetailsCreateSerializer
        elif self.action in ["partial_update"]:
            return IndexDetailsPatchSerializer
        else:
            return self.serializer_class

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = self.get_object()
            return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            return Response({"message": "Instance doesnot exists"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            self.get_object()
        except:
            return Response({"message": "Instance doesnot exists"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if len(serializer.data.keys()) < 2:
                return Response({"message": "please provide somedata to update"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                super().partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
                return Response({"message": "Data updated Successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"message": serilizer_validation(serializer)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"message": "data created successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({"message": serilizer_validation(serializer)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and following is the swagger auto schema code -

```
class IndexDetailsSwagger:
    @staticmethod
    def create ():
        doc = swagger_auto_schema (
            tags = ["indexdetails"],
            operation_summary= 'Add IndexDetails details',
            operation_description='Add information about IndexDetails',
            request_body= IndexDetailsCreateSerializer,
            responses={
                    200:openapi.Response(description="response on successful creation of data",
                                        examples={"application/json": {"message":"data created successfully"}}),
                    400:openapi.Response(description="response on unsuccessful creation of data",
                                        examples={"application/json": {"message":{"field_1":"error details","field_2":"error details","field_n":"error detail"}}})                  
                      },
            consumes=[ 'multipart/form-data', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ],
                    properties={
            'Documents_Manager': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'IndexDetails': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'nested_field': IndexDetailsCreateSerializer
        }

        )
        return doc
    

    @staticmethod
    def update():
        doc = swagger_auto_schema(
            tags = ["indexdetails"],
            operation_summary='Update IndexDetails details',
            operation_description= 'Update information of record in IndexDetails',
            request_body= IndexDetailsPatchSerializer,
            responses = {200: openapi.Response(description="response on successfull updation of data",
                                        examples={"application/json": {"message":"data updated successfully"}}),
                       400:openapi.Response(description="response on unsuccessfull updation of data",
                                        examples={"application/json": [{"message":"error string"}, {"message":"please provide somedata to update"}]}),
                        404:openapi.Response(description="response on incorrect id",
                                         examples={"application/json": {"message":"Instance doesnot exists"}})                  
                      }
        )
        return doc
```

Swagger documentation won't load when I am using the parser_classes in views code, if I comment it out, the documentation loads but I need to upload files so the default JSON parser won't do. Also if  I remove the nested serializer code , multipartparser and formparser works, so I think the problem is with using nested serializer that has a filefield.

I am new to coding, so kindly excuse me if my code is amateurish or if the language is incorrect.